# mysql default login password in linux. version 5.5

Tags: mysql, linux

i installed mysql-client-5.5 using apt-get in Debian OS. after installation i tried to log in using command "mysql -u root -p -h localhost" or with "mysql -u root -h localhost". It is asking for the MySQL password. But i did not set up any password. I even searched for default password but i did not get any.

I am getting error :

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Please tell me what is the default password for MYSQL.

Comment: Reset the password is best way, refer: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password

Comment: Run it
`/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
mysql --user=root mysql
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOUR_PASSWORD') WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='root';
exit;`

Comment: @TamilSelvan, +1 but don't forget to restart mysql again to go back to enforcing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

After installing mysql run $mysql_secure_installation as a superuser, this will prompt you to enter a root password or just press enter if none. Since you do not have a default password, just press enter and you will be prompeted to enter a new password for root. After entering the password, confirm and you will be logged in.